# How do I write this SQL query using Linq/Lambda?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lambda, group-by

I've up until now only written simple queries using lambda like `(c => c.UserID == uID)` and etc., But now I have a more advanced `SQL query`. I wish to run against the model I've created using `Entity Framework`.

Problem is i cant figure out how to use group by on multiple columns and also do a `distinct` `count` on the column `ObjectGUID`. This is the SQL Query that works fine when I run it in SQL Server management studio.

```
SELECT YEAR(logdate) as year, MONTH(logdate) as month, COUNT(distinct ObjectGUID) as ammount
FROM table
WHERE ExportTemplate = 'template' AND LogDate >= '2008-01-01 00:00:00:000'
GROUP BY YEAR(logdate), MONTH(logdate)
Order By YEAR(logdate), MONTH(logdate)
```

Is it better to combine this with linq or could it all be done by lambda expressions? Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create new anonymous type for groupping;

```
from x in Model
group by new { x.Date.Year, x.Date.Month } into g
order by g.Key.Year, g.Key.Month
select new
{
    g.Key.Year,
    g.Key.Month,
    Count = g.Select(s => s.ObjectGUID).Distinct().Count()
}
```

Something like this should do the trick (not tested though). Adding `where` conditions should be easy.

Comment: I get this error: Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access. This is for the distinct count line

Comment: yeah, might be due to not named property - try it now, added `Count` as property name

Comment: Thank you. It works! Now I need to put it inside a model for the view hmm :)